# JQuery selector for the P tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, output

I have a problem with selecting all the `<P>` tags in an HTML document using the Jquery library.
This is a part from my HTMl:

```
<p> This whole page is just for developmental purposes only, so feel free to do whatever you want </p>
<p> Эта страница - только в целях развития. Так, чувствовать себя вправе сделать все, что хотите</p>
```

and this is my JS:

```
$(function(){
     console.log($("p").html());
})
```

but when it comes to the output it gives me only the first paragraph, I can't understand why it selects only one elements and not all elements with the P tag, i would be very grateful if someone shows me where the problem is.

Comment: Why not take the time to read the docs. for something you plan to use. It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `.html()` gets the value of the first element. See [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

You can do an iteration using `.each()`

```
$("p").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [jQuery documentation for the `.html()` method](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

> Get the HTML contents of the **first element in the set of matched elements** or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

*(emphasis mine)*

When using the method as a getter, it is designed to return the content of *only* the first element in the collection. When used as a setter, it operates on the whole collection.

Comment: Worth noting that almost all jQuery methods used as getters work the same with regard to first matching selector...`text()` is an oddball exception

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the content from *all* the `<p>` tags, you can iterate through them with `.map()` and then `.join()` the result

```
console.log($("p").get().map(p => $(p).html()).join(" "));
```